# Laravel request validation image required in create but not required in update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

> **ProductsRequest.php** code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'          => 'required
                            |min:'.trans('validation_standards.names.min').'
                            |max:'.trans('validation_standards.names.max').'
                            |unique:products,name,'.$this -> product_id,


        'barcode'       => 'size:'.trans('validation_standards.barcode.size').'
                            |unique:products,barcode,'.$this -> product_id,

        'category_id'   => 'required
                            |exists:categories,id',

        'seasons_id'    => 'required
                            |exists:seasons,id',

                           // REQUIRED IMAGE ONLY IN STORE
        'image'         => 'required
                            |image|mimes:'.trans('validation_standards.images.extensions').'
                            |max:'.trans('validation_standards.images.file_size'),

        'description'   => 'nullable
                            |min:'.trans('validation_standards.descriptions.min').'
                            |max:'.trans('validation_standards.descriptions.max'),
    ];
}
```

These rules apply for both **store and update** methods.

> Problem is:

I want the image to be required only on **store** and not required in **update**, since user can just update the product basic info without choosing a new image for the product every time he update the product.

> What I have tried:

I have tried to create two different **ProductsRequest one for store and other for update** but I know that this achievement is not the best achievement because my code must be DRY.

Comment: Do you require both `category_id` and `seasons_id` when creating the resource as well?

Comment: @PeterSowah yes because both of them may be updated and both of them is required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in your `ProductsRequest` file;

```
public function rules()
{
    if(request()->isMethod('put')) // could be patch as well
    {
         // Update rules here - Don't require image here
return [
    'name' => 'required
              |min:'.trans('validation_standards.names.min').'
              |max:'.trans('validation_standards.names.max').'
              |unique:products,name,'.$this->product_id,
    'barcode' => 'size:'.trans('validation_standards.barcode.size').'
                 |unique:products,barcode,'.$this->product_id,

    'category_id'   => 'required|exists:categories,id',

    'seasons_id'    => 'required|exists:seasons,id',

                       // REQUIRED IMAGE ONLY IN STORE
    'image' => 'required|image|mimes:'.
                trans('validation_standards.images.extensions').'                         
                |max:'.trans('validation_standards.images.file_size'),
    'description' => 'nullable                        
                |min:'.trans('validation_standards.descriptions.min').'                      
                |max:'.trans('validation_standards.descriptions.max'),
];
    }else{
         // store rules here - require image here
         return [
    'name' => 'required
              |min:'.trans('validation_standards.names.min').'
              |max:'.trans('validation_standards.names.max').'
              |unique:products,name,'.$this->product_id,
    'barcode' => 'size:'.trans('validation_standards.barcode.size').'
                 |unique:products,barcode,'.$this->product_id,

    'category_id'   => 'required|exists:categories,id',

    'seasons_id'    => 'required|exists:seasons,id',

                       // REQUIRED IMAGE ONLY IN STORE
    'image' => 'image|mimes:'.
                trans('validation_standards.images.extensions').'                         
                |max:'.trans('validation_standards.images.file_size'),
    'description' => 'nullable                        
                |min:'.trans('validation_standards.descriptions.min').'                      
                |max:'.trans('validation_standards.descriptions.max'),
];
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I will try this solution

Comment: I don't have the `$request` variable in the `ProductRequest.php` file..

Comment: Instead of `$request()->isMethod('put')` use `request()->isMethod('put')`

Answer (score 7):

Use `required_without` rules

If primary key and element with name is `id` exist in your array

```
'image'         => 'required_without:id`
```

If primary key and element with name is `product_id` exist in your array

```
 'image'         => 'required_without:product_id`
```

You can get more detail from [laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)

Comment: What is the `id` that you wrote in the first line of code? I understand the `product_id` that I am going to send with the patch request

Comment: Ok then just use what you have in array.

Comment: I have `product_id` in the update method so how I add that with `required_with`?

Comment: Sorry its my bad you need to use 'required_without'

Comment: The problem is that I am sending the `product_id` in the URL and I don't have anything to differentiate between both requests except `POST` and `PATCH` request..

Comment: I know its old but in that situations send a hidden `id` field in the form and use ``required_without:id``

Answer (score 2):

```
public function rules()
{
    $image = request()->isMethod('put') ? 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg|max:8000' : 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg|max:8000';
    return [
        'image' => $image,

    ];
}
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If your route is something like this one (which should be)

```
 Route::post('products/{id}/update', 'ProductController@updateProduct')->name('products.update');
```

And you will call this route as

```
route('products.update', $product->id);
```

`$product->id` will be available in your form request and you can validate your form request for both create and update like this.

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            // All other rules
            'image' => $this->id == null ? 'required|image|mimes:'.
                trans('validation_standards.images.extensions').'                         
                |max:'.trans('validation_standards.images.file_size') : 
                'image|mimes:'.trans('validation_standards.images.extensions').'                         
                |max:'.trans('validation_standards.images.file_size')
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Config in translations? Bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

Just this few lines can solve your problems...
 You have to check there image have or not, like this.

**Rules in a private or protected function**

```
  private function validateRequest($request)
     {
        //This is for Update without required image, this will check that In DB image have or not

        $product = Product::find($request->product_id);
        $rules = [];
        if ($product) :
           if ($product->product_image == null):
              $rules['product_image'] = 'required|image|max:1999';
           endif;



     //This is for regular validation
       else :
          $rules = [
               'category_id'   => 'required|integer|not_in:-- Select Category --',
               'product_image' => 'required|image|max:1999',
             ];
       endif;
         return $rules;
    }
```